# Rate node connectedness in a routing graph

Tags: algorithm, routes, graph-algorithm

I have a directed, weighted routing graph (ca. 10^5 edges, 4 edges per node, lots of circles).

Each edge has a cost associated with it. How can I rate the "connectedness" of each node? It should be a measure of how cheap it is to reach other nodes from this one.

How does everything change if every node gets a reliability factor (the probability that the chosen path containing that node will fail and a new one must be found)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem you've put forth in many terms matches the use case of the [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm.

I won't discuss how the algorithm works in general since there are a lot many blogs/videos available online which already explains it in great detail. One of my personal favourite short video on the same is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8HtO7Gd5q0).

Now lets see how does the algorithm fits for your use case. Let's define `connectedness` of a node *x* as *C(x)*. We can rephrase your given statement *"how cheap it is to reach other nodes from this node"* to *"how likely are we to end up on the given node in a random walk across the graph such that we are biased to take edges whose costs are less"*.

The statement to a large extent relates to the ideology behind the PageRank algorithm. We just need to consider how to include the edge cost for our working.

The original PageRank algorithm uniformly divides the page rank of a given node to all it's adjacent node *(denoted as PR(y) / OUT(y) in formula)*. We on the other hand needs to be more biased towards edges with lower cost for which I'll recommend modifying the formula to,

*(SUM-EDGES-COST(y) - EDGE-COST(x, y)) * (C(y) / SUM-EDGES-COST(y))*

instead of the traditional *C(x) / OUT(x)*. We take the difference *(SUM-EDGES-COST(y) - EDGE-COST(x, y))* since in our scenario lower edge cost means more `connectedness`. Another possibility is to apply `softmax` function to the edge cost for each node as a normalisation strategy.

As to answer the part about having a reliability factor, given by *R(x)* for a node *x*, we can just multiply it directly to *C(x)* in the formula.

To wrap things up,

[image: formula]

should match your given scenario.

What I've presented here is just one possibility which I can think from the top of my mind and it's highly likely that it just might not work out. All I can hope is that it helps you out in some or the other way. Cheers! :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that PR is applicable in this case. If A links to B and later adds a link to C, the PR of B decreases, even though it is as connected as before. That shouldn't be that way, or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Would some kind of centrality work? Maybe betweenness centrality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality